# \ifmmode doesn't work in the Todo list

Tags: math-mode, todonotes

Feeding

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}%
\listoftodos
\todo{\(\ifmmode MATH \else TEXT\fi\)}%%% $…$ instead of \(…\) fails as well.
\end{document}
```

to `pdflatex` yields

[image: output]

However, the expected outcome is  printed in the Todo list, and not .

Why does this happen, who is the culprit, and what to do?

The same issue: https://github.com/henrikmidtiby/todonotes/issues/63 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that when TeX does a `\write` (for instance when adding the entry to the todolist) it is in no mode and doesn't typeset, but expands macros and conditionals.

You might define your own robust command:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\MathModeTF}{mm}{\ifmmode #1\else #2\fi}
```

or

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\MathModeTF}[2]{\ifmmode #1\else #2\fi}
```

(I'd prefer the former) so the evaluation of the conditional is delayed until typesetting is being done. Call it like

```
\MathModeTF{MATH}{TEXT}
```

On the other hand, the LaTeX kernel already has `\TextOrMath{TEXT}{MATH}` with just the arguments switched.

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\begin{document}%
\listoftodos
\todo{\(\TextOrMath{TEXT}{MATH}\)}%%% $…$ instead of \(…\) fails as well.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of a "general" solution, this answer demonstrates how to "solve" the issue with `\protect` etc..

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{todonotes}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}%
\listoftodos
\todo{\(\protect\ifmmode MATH \protect\else TEXT\protect\fi\)}
\todo{\protecting{\(\ifmmode MATH \else TEXT\fi\)}}  % need etoolbox

\end{document}
```

Both ways work.

---

General question: [What is the difference between Fragile and Robust commands? When and why do we need \protect?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/4736/250119)

Other questions about moving argument in `\todo`: [1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/368658/250119) [2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/531645/250119)

Comment: \ifmmode is a primitive TeX command though, so in LaTeX documents I think it's not very recommended.